# How to access a running laravel project inside a docker container?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, port

I have a docker container running on port 80 with PHP, apache, composer, and laravel.
Inside this container, it's running a laravel app on port 8000.
This App is located in /var/www.
I already exposed the ports in Dockerfile and bind them in docker-compose.yml
I am a beginner in PHP and laravel, so I don't know what's going on.

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.2-apache

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git curl zip unzip libzip-dev

RUN composer global require laravel/installer

ENV PATH="/root/.composer/vendor/bin:${PATH}"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

RUN echo 'alias run="php artisan serve"' >> ~/.bashrc

EXPOSE 80 8000
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:

  dw2_apache_php:
    build: .
    container_name: dw2_apache_php
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8000:8000
```

I expected that when I exposed the ports and bound them, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to run your docker container you'll need to map the port the app is running on with the port you exposed.

If running localhost I would typically do something like this

```
docker run -p 3000:8080 IMAGE_ID
```

3000 representing the port you would be entering in the browser

8080 representing the port you exposed in the container

IMAGE_ID you would need to fill in with the appropriate value

Edit:

Additionally, unless you have a specific reason, you shouldn't need this line

```
RUN echo 'alias run="php artisan serve"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

I would remove it and just add this after the EXPOSE

```
CMD php artisan serve
```

Comment: The question includes Compose `ports:` already, which are equivalent to the `docker run -p` option.